# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I just installed keras and am new. I'm running windows, installed tensorflow by pip, python 3.6. Tried to run "from keras.models import Sequential" and got this error. Any ideas?

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-490b9437d5d1> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.models import Sequential

C:\Users\unknow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

C:\Users\unknow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 
      8 # Globally-importable utils.

C:\Users\unknow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>()
      1 from six.moves import range
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 from .. import backend as K
      4 
      5 

C:\Users\unknow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>()
     81 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     82     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 83     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     84 else:
     85     raise ValueError('Unknown backend: ' + str(_BACKEND))

C:\Users\unknow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages
      3 from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
      4 from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
      5 from tensorflow.python.ops import functional_ops

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned whether you wanted to install with CPU or GPU support. My answer is for GPU, but most of the steps remain same if you want to install for CPU.(You can skip Step 3, Step 4 and Step 5 for CPU)

I was having a similar problem with my installation. I used the installation steps given on [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). They worked fine when I installed TF on Ubuntu 16.04.

I got hold of the steps given [here](https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation) and they worked fine for me. I would recommend you to try them once.